# How to get ID from parent object inside child object when creating it? (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

**Overview**

I'm using ASP.NET Core with MVC.

I am trying to make a simple **helpdesk** system as an experiment.

It has 2 objects, an **Inquiry** and a **Comment**.

- An Inquiry has a list of comments.
- A comment has the ID of the Inquiry it belongs to.

**My question is**

How can I get the ID of the Inquiry (which is a parent of the comment being created) to be added to a property in the comment?

---

**Code examples**

**CommentsController.Create**

I have tried the 2 POST examples, both seem to capture the form data from the comment but I don't know how to also bring in the Inquiry ID in that form data. When I am creating a child comment. The Inquiry ID was added to the model I sent to the Create view but lost when submitting the form in that view. The GET example works as intended.

```
    // GET: Comments/Create
    public IActionResult Create([FromRoute] int id) //id = InquiryID

    // POST: Comments/Create
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CommentCreationDTO commentCreationDTO)

    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm]CommentCreationDTO commentCreationDTO)
```

**Views/Comments/Create.cshtml**

```
@model HelpDesk2018.Models.CommentCreationDTO
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}
<h2>Create</h2>
<h4>Comment</h4>
<hr/>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-controller="Comments" asp-action="Create" method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.Comment.TimePosted" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.Comment.TimePosted" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Comment.TimePosted" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.Comment.Text" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.Comment.Text" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Comment.Text" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

**Elaboration of the current flow in the MVC program for better understanding**

To add comments to the Inquiry I have made the following setup.

1. A button on the Inquiry detail view triggers an action on the InquiryController named "CreateComment". This redirects to the Comments controller with the ID of the inquiry.
2. The CommentsController received the redirect plus the attached InquiryID. It then sends back the Create view for creating comments, in the view a CommentCreation object is sent in as model. This holds the ID of the parent Inquiry as well as a new/empty comment.
3. On the comment creation view I enter the comment information and submit.
4. The form info submitted is now "caught" by the Create and I can see the information of the comment. However, and **this is the issue**, the ID for the parent Inquiry was lost in the process and now is set to the default value of 0 (as it's an integer).

---

**Models**

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents one inquiry on the helpdesk.
/// Category, Country and RelatedProduct should perhaps be objects instead of strings.
/// </summary>
public class Inquiry : TextPost
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Solved { get; set; }
    public bool Private { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; } = new List<Comment>();
    public string Category { get; set; }

    #region optional properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Which country this inquiry is most relevant for. E.g. Denmark, Sweden, Norway etc., but can also be "All" or the name of a specific market.
    /// </summary>
    public string Country { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// In case the inquiry is related to one or more products. Should perhaps be an object in it's own right instead of a string as it is now.
    /// </summary>
    public string RelatedProduct { get; set; }
    #endregion
}

public class Comment : TextPost
{
    public int InquiryID { get; set; }
}

public class TextPost
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimePosted { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// The main text.
    /// </summary>
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class CommentCreationDTO
{
    public int IDOfInquiryBelongingTo { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// The comment that is being created.
    /// </summary>
    public Comment Comment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is the first method you have shown the GET? (in which case it should not have the  model as the parameter - just and `int id` representing the `InquiryId`. And you need to include a route value in the form for `InquiryId`, or include a hidden input for it so that it is posted back

Comment: It's a POST. Added some clarification plus now show my GET.

Comment: @StephenMuecke if you can see any solution to getting the Inquiry and the Comment connected, please let me know. It does not have to be the exact way I try now.

Comment: You have not shown your model(s), so all I can do is not that you need a route value or hidden input that binds to your `InquiryId` property

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added the models now. In the GET Create on CommentsController the inquiry id is being routed in. But I cannot seem to get both the form data for the new comment and also have this inquiry id added to the comment.

Comment: You are still missing the `CommentCreationDTO` model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke right, fixed now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182668/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-doh09).

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a route/query string value in the `<form>` or include a hidden input for `IDOfInquiryBelongingTo`, so that its value is sent in the request and will be bound to your model.

However, view models should not contain data models when editing data (your `Comment` property), and `TimePosted` appears to be a property that should not be editable by the user. I recommend you first modify the view model to

```
public class CommentVM
{
    public int? ID { get; set; } // if you also want to use this for editing existing comments
    [Required]
    public int? InquiryID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a comment")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Your GET method will now return an instance of `CommentVM` to the view

```
public IActionResult Create([FromRoute] int id) //id = InquiryID
{
    CommentVM model = new CommentVM
    {
        InquiryID = id
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model ....CommentVM
<form asp-controller="Comments" asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="InquiryID" /> // add hidden input
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Text" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Text" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Text" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

And in the POST method, map the view model to the data model

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm]CommentVM model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    Comment comment = new Comment
    {
        InquiryID = model.InquiryID,
        Text = model.Text,
        TimePosted = DateTime.Now,
        .... // set other properties (User etc) as required
    };
    // save and redirect
    ....
}
```